# Python sum up array based on key

Tags: python, arrays

What is the best way to sum up based on the key parameter

E.g.

```
x  = [[0,"xxx",100],[1,"yyy",100],[1,"xxx",100]]
```

How to sum up .. to make it `[[0,"xxx",200],[1,"yyy",100]]`

So the first label in the list will be the main one and all the rest will be summed up.

Looking for something easy (as all my ideas went into the mess...)

- ANy hints, ideas, examples will be appreciated

Comment: Hint: use a dictionary.

Comment: Why is the first element in the resulting list `[0,"xxx",200]` zero when the constituent values in that element are 0 and 1? What does that first element represent?

Comment: +1 for dictionary.  Are you really doing min([0]), sum([2]) grouped by [1] or . do you actually want [["xxx",200],["yyy",100]] ?

Comment: Dict.... solving the problem..... Thank YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapReduce style:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from functools import reduce

myList = [[0, 'xxx', 100], [1, 'yyy', 100], [1, 'xxx', 100]]

# filter data: remove first coordinate
map(lambda x: x[1:], myList)
[['xxx', 100], ['yyy', 100], ['xxx', 100]]

# sort data by first coordinate (key)
sorted(map(lambda x: x[1:], myList), key=itemgetter(0))
# [['xxx', 100], ['xxx', 100], ['yyy', 100]]

# reducer function that adds up items with the same key 
# this works because input list is sorted by key
def myReducer(a,b):
    if a!=[] and b[0] == a[-1][0]:
        c = a.pop()
        return a + [[c[0],c[1]+b[1]]]
    else:
        return a + [b]

# putting it all together
reduce(myReducer, sorted(map(lambda x: x[1:], myList), key=itemgetter(0)), [])
```

For very long lists this is suitable for parallelization with multiprocessing.

Answer (score -1):

I think you actually want something like this:

```
x  = [[0,"xxx",100],[1,"yyy",100],[1,"xxx",100]]

result={}
for item in x:
    result[item[1]] = result.get(item[1], 0) + item[2]

print(result)
```

Comment: Uh Dicts..... ***** I was trying to solve it by playing with array loop only....